# Explain Mesh.MarkDynamic

Tags: unity, mesh

As the [reference page](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.MarkDynamic.html) says, this function/method is used to optimize a mesh for frequent updates, but the description seems a little bit unclear.
What should I consider before using it in my code? Would there be any 'side effects' like heightened memory usage etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When setting a mesh as Dynamic, you are indicating to the API that the vertex buffer contents are going to change often. Most underlying rendering systems (DirectX, for example) will manage the memory associated with a vertex buffer differently if it knows that the buffer is static or dynamic - for example the buffer can live entirely on the GPU if it is static, whereas it needs to be pushed from main RAM to GPU RAM when it changes.

Classic examples are particle systems, the results of CPU-side skinning or some cloth simulation results.